# Filtro *ngFor async data

Tags: typescript, async, angular-6, filter

Como se aplica um filtro em um *ngFor async, o array do *ngFor vem de um Observable.

```
lotes$: Observable<Lote[]>;

*ngFor="let lote of (lotes$  | lancamentosFilter:searchText) | async; let i = index"
```

meu filtro, porém não funciona

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { isArray } from 'util';

@Pipe({
    name: 'lancamentosFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class LancamentosFilter implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], filter: any): any {

        if(items !=null)
        items.forEach(obs => (console.log(obs)));


        if (!items || !filter || !isArray(items)) {
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter(item => item.historico.indexOf(filter.historico) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando seu pipe antes do async, ou seja, ele está recebendo um Observable e não um array.

Você deve mudar a ordem dos pipes:

```
(lotes$  | async) | lancamentosFilter:searchText
```